# Magento 1.9: Get products of which product X is an upsell

Tags: magento, product

As we are using exchange tables on our webshops, where we use the upsell-functionality to point out the right exchange product, I'm looking for a solution for the following:

Fact:
 - [Product X] is set to be an upsell item for i.e. 50 separate products in the backend

What I need:
 - On the product page of [Product X] I want to list the product names of all products that have [Product X] as an upsell item.

This seems like we have to loop through a complete product collection to make an array of these products, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?
The separate products I'm talking about are all placed in a certain category, so it's possible to filter on the category for the product collection.

Looking forward to your thoughts / solution(s)! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i am not sure that you can do it via Magento admin panel. Magento Store Manager has related product generator so there you can set up your up-sales.
more detail in our documentation https://store-manager-for-magento-doc.emagicone.com/tools/6-related-products-generator